# Why doesn't this regex work with preg_*?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex: `/(<br\s*/{0,1}>)*$/gi`.

The purpose of this is to match an unknown number of  `<br>` tags from the end of a string which may be badly formatted.  The string will contain no HTML other than break tags.

This works fine in Grant Skinner's testing tool (http://regexr.com?303ff), but fails when used in PHP with `preg_replace`.

The following returns an empty string, but I was expecting the original string without any `<br>` tags at the end:

```
$string = 'Here is some text<br><br>And here is some more<br><br>and this is followed by a load of unnecessary breaks<Br><br/><br   /><br /><br><br    ><br><br>';
echo preg_replace('/(<br\s*/{0,1}>)*$/gi','',$string);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @webarto: Why would he want to do that? When using a regex tester, use one that uses the same engine (preferably even in the same language environment) as your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash; it terminates your regex early and then causes an error because of unexpected characters in the *regex options* area. Besides that, remove the `g` modifier which does not exist in PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('/(<br\s*\/?>)*$/i','',$string);
```

Another option would be using a different delimiter (`/` is sub-optimal when dealing with html):

```
echo preg_replace('#(<br\s*/?>)*$#i', '', $string);
```

Sidenote: You can and should use `?` instead of `{0,1}`

Comment: I've tried it with an escaped slash, but it doesn't help - `/(<br\s*\/?>)*$/gi`.  I used the {0,1} form because if the line containing this regex gets commented out the `?>` portion is interpreted as the end of the PHP.

Comment: Answer updated. Remove the `g` modifier. Then it works. You should really enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `display_errors = on` (php.ini) on your development system. Then you get useful warnings telling you immediately what's wrong.

Comment: You're quite right. I didn't realize that `g` isn't allowed. Thank you!